# Elasticsearch ctx append json object to array

Tags: elasticsearch

I am appending string to the array using painless and ctx API call. 
For simple strings it works fine.

My loaded data is: 
Request time: 26/Mar/2019:09:25:47 +0100, Cookie: sessionid=760ddsaa323

```
POST test/doc/948650eff51e70ecf0e7c38d4afa442d/_update  
{  
"script" : {
    "source": "if(ctx._source.session_cookie_log != null) {ctx._source.session_cookie_log.add(params.newsupp)}",
     "params": {
      "newsupp": "Request time: 26/Mar/2019:09:25:47 +0100, Cookie: sessionid=760ddsaa323"
    }
 }
}
```

However my requirement changed and I have to load JSON object to the array instead of string.

My object that I am attempting to load now is:

```
{
  "Request time": "26/Mar/2019:09:25:47 +0100",
  "Cookie": "sessionid=760ddsaa323"
}
```

How can I adjust my API call for loading the JSON object instead of a string?

Answer (score -1):

Change mapping of the field (`session_cookie_log` in your case) to nested.

Reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html